# Netbeans: how to separate application logic from view?

Tags: netbeans6.8

When creating a desktop application in Netbeans,

what is the recommended approach in separating application logic from the view (gui builder) ? The two files are generated by the gui builder in Netbeans.

Comment: This seems to be more about Java and design patterns than the particular IDE you're using, edited to reflect that.

Comment: Actually no. I was NOT talking about MVC, I am talking specifically about the view and app source code generated by Netbeans.

Comment: The example behind the first link of my answer was created using *NetBeans Swing GUI Builder*, check if this provides some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read the Sun article about [Java SE Application Design With MVC](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/mvc/).

Here is an example: [Model-View-Controller (MVC) Structure](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well the short and general answer (for any object oriented language) is to use the [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) or MVC design pattern.

What's so cool about this, is that in decoupling the view (the interface code) from the model (your app logic) you can easily add multiple interfaces (such as a command line and a GUI), or port to different platforms, while keeping your back end business logic the same.

Check out the book [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) by the "Gang of Four". It is *the* canonical design pattern book. In addition to MVC, there are a ton of other really useful design patterns. Even skimming it will pay great dividends when you go to architect some software.